# Positive Hausdorff measure and $L^{2}$ convergence.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, hausdorff-measure

i would like to know the relation between the positive Hausdorff measure and $L^{2}$ convergence in the ((1.3) existente theorem)

[image]

Comment: You'll probably want to learn at bit of the $\LaTeX$ and MathJax [to post mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  From the title and text of the body of your Question it is impossible to guess that you are interested in a Dirichlet problem for a second-order PDE.  Being able to write with math notation (rather than only post a picture) will give you the ability to express your interests more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the functions $v_k=u_k-u^0$ and take $R>0$ large enough so that $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S\cap B_R)>0$. We have that $\nabla v_k$ are bounded in $L^2(\Omega\cap B_R)$ and they vanish on $S\cap B_R$. Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050619/poincar%C3%A9-inequality-for-a-subspace-of-h1-omega) (and noticing that $\Gamma$ doesn't need to be part of the boundary there), you realize that the functions $v_k$ are bounded in $H^1(\Omega)$, from which you get $u_k-u^0 \to u-u^0$ and $\nabla(u_k-u^0) \rightharpoonup \nabla(u-u^0)$ in $L^2(\Omega\cap B_R)$.

Basically, the part that you underlined is a consequence of a variant of the Poincaré inequality for $H^1_0(\Omega)$ where the functions vanish on a sufficiently fat set instead of the boundary.

Comment: Hey @Federico's what is the importance of the choice of large $R$ such that $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(S\cap B_{R})>0$?