# A generalized Poincaré inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an appropriate open set, let $f \in H^1(\Omega)^*$ with $f(1)\neq 0$. Then there exists $C=C(f)\geq 0$ with: $$\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2+\int_\Omega u^2\leq C\left ( (f(u))^2+\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2\right),\quad \forall u \in H^1(\Omega)$$

Is this theorem true for $\Omega$ bounded open? I could't find any reference on this online, only for more complicated $\Omega$s.

**Context**: I'm studying the well posedness of the $2$nd weak formulation of elliptic PDEs with Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: One proof goes by contradiction. It needs compactness of the embedding $H^1\hookrightarrow L^2$. Direct proofs of related inequalities need density of smooth functions in $H^1$. In either case, some boundary regularity is needed.

Comment: @daw Can you please point me to a statement where the regularity is precised?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality#Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Wirtinger_inequality

Comment: @daw Thank you but I'm looking for the version that includes the functional $f$.

Comment: you can modify the proof of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050619/poincar%C3%A9-inequality-for-a-subspace-of-h1-omega to your situation